# How to make the table responsive when exporting from Mysql via PHP with EZPDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, export

I've a problem with showing data with ezpdf from mysql via php. The contents of Description are very long so it will pass through the paper when exported. Is there any way to solve this?

```
<?php session_start();
require 'config.php';
require 'class.ezpdf.php';
require 'cek/cek_session.php';

$sql  = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM arsip WHERE unitkerja = '$sesen_uk' ORDER BY id_arsip ASC");
$i    = 1;
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
  while($tampil = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
  {
    $data[$i] = array ( 'No'      => $i,
                    'Description'        => $tampil['desc'],
                    'Department'        => $tampil['dpt'],
                    'Location' => $tampil['location'],
                  );
            $i++;
  }  

  $pdf = new Cezpdf('A4','landscape');
  $pdf->ezSetCmMargins(1, 3, 3, 3);
  $pdf->ezText('Report', 17, array('justification' => 'center'));
  $pdf->ezSetDy(-10);

  $pdf->ezTable($data, '', '', '');
  $pdf->ezSetDy(-50);

  $pdf->ezStartPageNumbers(799,50, 10, 4);
  $pdf->ezStream();
}  
  else
  {
    echo '<script>alert("Belum ada data");location.replace("report.php")</script>';
 }
 ?>
```

The output should be like this:

http://tinypic.com/r/2zyl9xj/9

Any help will be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can add width in option like below :

```
   $options=array(

        'width'=>550

       );

$pdf->ezTable($data,$cols='',$title='',$options);
```

with width the text will be wraped